# Updating a column in a dataframe with values from the same column another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a larger dataframe in which there's a column that I would like to update with new values from a smaller dataframe only where row values for another column match. A left join has the correct rows but two columns of the values I want "updated" (left and right). I have tried a left merge with drops but of course that wipes out the values in the column I'm trying to update wherever the matching column doesn't match. I've also tried variations of this:

```
tips.loc[tips['tip'] < 2, 'tip'] = 2
```

but I get an error about series lengths needing to match because the table I'm updating from is smaller. I looked at DataFrame.combine_first() also but the docs don't show it takes any options and doesn't produce what I'm looking for either.

Here's an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CAT': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'Value': [12, 34, np.NaN, 43, 21]})
  CAT  Value
0   A     12
1   B     34
2   C    NaN
3   D     43
4   E     21

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'CAT': ['C', 'F', 'G'], 'Value': [22, 99, 44]})
  CAT  Value
0   C     22
1   F     99
2   G     44
```

the result should look like this:

```
 CAT  Value
0   A     12
1   B     34
2   C     22
3   D     43
4   E     21
```

Though the left frame in this example has NaN being updated, I'm not looking exclusively for this case. I want to overwrite whatever value is there. Any help? Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to replace `Value` from `df` with the corresponding `Value` in `df2`, if the value exists. I.e., assuming you had a `CAT` F that had a corresponding value of `36` in `df`, you would want that to be replaced by 99 (from `df2`).

Using `merge`:

```
df= df.merge(df2, on = 'CAT', how = 'left')
df['Value'] = df[['Value_x', 'Value_y']].apply(lambda x: np.where(df['Value_y'].isna(), df['Value_x'], df['Value_y'])).drop(columns = ['Value_y'])
df.drop(columns = ['Value_x', 'Value_y'])
```

Output:

```
  CAT  Value
0   A   12.0
1   B   34.0
2   C   22.0
3   D   43.0
4   E   21.0
5   F   99.0
```